# Need unix code to modify excel sheet (.xsl format)

Tags: excel, unix, aix

i am trying to write a code to open an excel (.xsl)  and add new lines to existing content and then save it and close it. Want to do this from Unix batch script. Was this possible ? i am not aware of perl/python etc. i know only unix to code this.

Comment: .XLS files are binary content; they don't have "lines", and you can't write to them using a batch script. You'll need to learn the file structure in order to update it or find a third-party library that you can use. Google or Bing may find you such a library (asking for it here is off-topic).

Comment: Can you save the file to a csv format? After that you can just append lines to the file (with echo, printf or any other combination of commands)